# switchToLatest in Combine doesn't behave as expected

Tags: swift, combine

I've been trying to replicate `flatMapLatest` from RxSwift in Combine, I've read in a few places that the solution is to use `.map(...).switchToLatest`

I'm finding some differences between the two, and I'm not sure if it's my implementation/understanding which is the problem.

In RxSwift if the upstream observable emits a stop event (completed or error) then the downstream observables created in the `flatMapLatest` closure will continue to emit events until they themselves emit a stop event:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func flatMapLatestDemo() {
    let mockTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
    let mockDataTask = PublishSubject<Void>()

    mockTrigger
        .flatMapLatest { mockDataTask }
        .subscribe(onNext: { print("RECEIVED VALUE") })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    mockTrigger.onNext(())
    mockTrigger.onCompleted()

    mockDataTask.onNext(()) // -> "RECEIVED VALUE" is printed
}
```

This same setup in Combine doesn't behave the same way:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func switchToLatestDemo() {
    let mockTrigger = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    let mockDataTask = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    mockTrigger
        .map { mockDataTask }
        .switchToLatest()
        .sink { print("RECEIVED VALUE") }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

    mockTrigger.send(())
    mockTrigger.send(completion: .finished)

    mockDataTask.send(()) // -> Nothing is printed, if I uncomment the finished event above then "RECEIVED VALUE" is printed
}
```

Is this intentional? If so, how do we replicate the behaviour of `flatMapLatest` in Combine?

If it's not intentional, file a radar I guess?

Answer (score 4):

I've using this Swift implementation by [sergdort](https://github.com/sergdort/CombineFeedback/blob/2f0362199e8df4a348c3c8dea0465027d6b261c5/Sources/CombineFeedback/FlatMapLatest.swift):

```
func flatMapLatest<T: Publisher>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) -> T) -> Publishers.SwitchToLatest<T, Publishers.Map<Self, T>> where T.Failure == Self.Failure {
    map(transform).switchToLatest()
}
```